# Remove last digit from integer and put zero in python

Tags: python, int

I have the small code, which is converting the integer to 10 bit binary and forming it as integer:

```
a = 2251
binary = bin(int(a))[2:].zfill(15)
print binary
```

it will give result as:

> 100011001011

and after that I want to remove the last four digits from `100011001011` and put zeros instead of that, means my final answer should be:

> 100011000000

please suggest if any good ideas...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with some simple [bit shifting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift):

```
>>> a = 2251
>>> a = (a >> 4) << 4  # <--
>>> print format(a, 'b')
100011000000
```

To demonstrate what's going on, imagine that `a` had the binary representation `1111 1111`:

```
a             == 11111111

a >> 4        == 00001111

(a >> 4) << 4 == 11110000
```

Comment: This has got to be the best way

Comment: @TimCastelijns Correct but here I don;t want`0b` in front of output

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple bitwise operation:

```
>>> a = 2251
>>> a = a & ~0b1111
>>> print format(a, 'b')
100011000000
```

Comment: (this is about twice as fast as @arshajii's answer, probably because it does only one binary operation)

Comment: Nice solution (+1), but if you're worried about bitwise-and being faster than two bit shifts, you're using the wrong language.